# How the open source Javascripts like AngularJS runs on client browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web

I am a newbie in web development. In my understanding, for static web content, we can use HTML and Javascript (for validation and some client side processing) and ASP.NET/JSP/PHP technologies are for dynamic content generation, server side processing and all.

In this case, how the custom javascript frameworks like AngularJS, node.js and all runs in client's browser? Is there some some runtime required for running them will gets downloaded when we try to load web pages which has those scripts?

Please clarify.

Adding some more info:
My question is, when we have many custom Javascript frameworks, how the browser can able to process those? And is there any plug-in/tiny framework that will get downloaded for the first time to run those scripts on client side? Got info from Cuberto saying that as all were Javascript the browser will know how to process it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right place for a question like this, but I'm not sure which other stack exchange site might be better suited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js doesn't run on the client - it is a standalone program that runs on an operating system. Usually, it is used for servers.

AngularJS is just a JavaScript framework. It's very big piece of JavaScript that you include in your HTML page like any other JavaScript - using a `<script>` tag.

Your question seems to be really about what is possible with JavaScript. The answer is simply, "a lot". The problem is that JavaScript lacks some features that help when developing very large applications (type declarations, arity checking, etc). That doesn't prevent you from writing great applications with JavaScript - look at Google Drive or some of the HTML5 games people have written. It just makes the process a little more difficult and potentially buggier.

Comment: You can do a lot with developer tools to help with the quality assurance when working with JavaScript though. Jshint/lint, unit tests etc can catch a lot of bugs at build time.

Comment: @Cuberto Thank you! My question is not about what and all possible with JavaScript. It is about the runtime. How those custom made scripts are running in the browser.

Comment: @Prasanna Yeah, then the answer is simply that they're just pure JavaScript, doing the things that JavaScript can do. There's nothing special about them - just a lot of lines of JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no runtime other than the built-in JavaScript engine in the browser. AngularJS is pure JavaScript.

To handle older browsers that are missing JavaScript features, AngularJS supplies fallback implementations of those (like array iterator functions etc.). That's pretty costly in development time though, which is why AngularJS is trying to abandon old platforms as soon as users move on to more modern browsers. Next version of AngularJS (1.3) will not support IE8 for instance.